# Select dependientes en reactjs con react-select

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, select, react-select

Estoy desarrollando una App en ReactJS, y tengo una página donde deseo mostrar dos select, uno dependiente del otro.

Estoy usando `react-select` y `@material-ui`.

En `dates`

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "202001"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "202002"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "202003"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "202004"
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "202005"
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "name": "202006"
  },
  {
    "id": 7,
    "name": "202007"
  }
]
```

tengo una lista de fechas que son las que están disponibles para seleccionar.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Select from "react-select";
...

const App = () => {

    ...

    const DateA = dates.map((item) => ({
        value: item.id,
        label: item.name,
    }));

    const DateB = dates.map((item) => ({
        value: item.id,
        label: item.name,
    }));

    const [dateA, setDateA] = React.useState(null);
    const [dateB, setDateB] = React.useState(null);

    function handleChangeDateA(value) {
        setDateA(value);
    }

    function handleChangeDateB(value) {
        setDateB(value);
    }

    return (
            <div className="App">
                <div className="col-3">
                    <Select
                        classes={classes}
                        styles={selectStyles}
                        inputId="DateA"
                        TextFieldProps={{
                            label: "DateA",
                            InputLabelProps: {
                            htmlFor: "DateA",
                            shrink: true,
                            },
                            placeholder: "DateA...",
                        }}
                        options={DateA}
                        components={components}
                        value={dateA}
                        onChange={handleChangeDateA}
                    />
                </div>
                <div className="col-3">
                    <Select
                        classes={classes}
                        styles={selectStyles}
                        inputId="DateB"
                        TextFieldProps={{
                            label: "DateB",
                            InputLabelProps: {
                                htmlFor: "DateB",
                                shrink: true,
                            },
                            placeholder: "DateB...",
                        }}
                        options={DateB}
                        components={components}
                        value={dateB}
                        onChange={handleChangeDateB}
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
    );
};

export default App;
```

La idea es que el select de `DateB` tome las fechas mayores a las que se selecciona en el select de `DateA`.

Cómo puedo hacer esto, sugerencias?

Comment: Se tiene un array de fechas `date`, con este array se llena el select de `Date A`, luego el usuario selecciona por ejemplo una fecha de `Junio 2020`, entonces se vacían las las fechas a partir de Junio 2020 en el select A , con esas fechas se llena el `Date B` (select B) y en el select A solo quedan las fechas debajo de junio 2020, ¿Puedes elaborar mas la pregunta?, si puedes agregar un extracto de los datos que hay en `dates` para ver en que formato vienen, eso sería de utilidad para poder apoyarte, saludos

Comment: @g.4 claro, la idea es hacer algo así a lo que estás describiendo: se tiene un array de fechas `date`, con este array se llena el select de `Date A`, luego el usuario selecciona por ejemplo una fecha de Junio 2020, entonces se guardan las fechas a partir de Junio 2020 para llenar el select de `Date B`. Lo que se busca es registrar esas dos fechas, pero que la segunda esté condicionada a la primera, que solo tome fechas mayores. Dale, actualizo la pregunta para mostrarte el array `date`. Muchas Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se puede hacer esto:

```
useEffect(() => {
        if (condition) {
         setDateB(value)
    }
          
   }, [DateA])
```